# Setting exact view area (rect) of QGraphicsScene in QGraphicsView - a better fitInView()?

Tags: c++, windows, qt4

I am failing in trying to restore a particular view (visible area) in a subclassed QGraphicsView on a subclassed QGraphicsScene.

The visible rectangle of the scene viewed should be

```
mapToScene( rect() ).boundingRect()
```

which is

```
QRectF(27.8261,26.9565 673.043x507.826)
```

I obtain these values in the destructor of QGraphicsView, they seem valid.

After restoring the window geometry, I am using said values in the first QGraphicsView::resizeEvent (the first event has an invalid old size `QSize(-1, -1)`) in the attempt to restore the area shown in view using

```
fitInView( QRectF(....) , Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
```

This triggers a number of scrollContentsBy events before showing the view, another resize and scroll event after, then the mainwindow showEvent fires, causing more resize scroll and resize events.
I am sure this sequence is neccessary for the GUI layout to build, but I am now confused as to how I could run fitInView once everything is set up.

Using a QTimer::singleShot to run the function well after the GUI is shown, I get approximately the desired result, but the matrix and viewed area differ:

```
ui->graphicsView->matrix();
ui->graphicsView->mapToScene( ui->graphicsView->rect()).boundingRect();
```

Before:

```
"[m11=1 m12=0 m21=0 m22=1 dx=0 dy=0] (x=27 y=27 w=774 h=508)"
```

Restored:

```
"[m11=0.954724 m12=0 m21=0 m22=0.954724 dx=0 dy=0] (x=17.8062 y=24.0907 w=810.705 h=532.091)"
```

So [fitInView()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView) does not serve my purpose very well - is there another, reliable way?

I'm using Qt 4.8.1 with MSVC2010

---

Another approach is to restore transform and window scroll position like so:

```
settings->setValue("view", mapToScene( rect() ).boundingRect() );
settings->setValue("transform", transform() );
settings->sync();
```

and restore them

```
QTransform trans = settings->value("transform", QTransform()).value<QTransform>();
QRectF view = settings->value( "view", QRectF() ).value<QRectF>();
setTransform( trans );
centerOn( view.center() );
```

But this method, too, has an offset.

Before

```
"[m11=4.96282 m12=0 m21=0 m22=4.96282 dx=0 dy=0] (x=29.6203 y=29.4188 w=155.96 h=104.981)"
```

After

```
"[m11=4.96282 m12=0 m21=0 m22=4.96282 dx=0 dy=0] (x=54.8076 y=53.8001 w=155.96 h=104.981)"
```

An offset also is present when scrollbars are hidden.
Moving the code to showEvent() does not affect result.

Comment: Regarding `fitInView( QRectF(....) , Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);` -- I changed this to Qt::KeepAspectRatio to ensure identical scale values of the transform matrix.

Comment: Disabling the view's scrollbars helps a little (scale diff appr. 0.01, position offset appr. 2-8 px).

Comment: Could the problem be caused by the INT scrollbars?

Answer (score 1):

What is finally working: in showEvent, restore the transform, restore scroll-bar values:

```
setTransform( trans );
verticalScrollBar()->setValue( v );
horizontalScrollBar()->setValue( h );
```

Scroll bar visibility does not affect the view position and size, they are just "overlays".

Comment: Such a great hint - thank you. Ive been struggling with this quite a while.